# Visual Basic richtextbox - setting specific text to Italic font style

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, richtextbox, text-formatting

I have created a Richtextbox, which produces text based on user-inputted variables as well as some basic formatting - eg:

```
name = txtname.text
richtextbox1.text = "Hello my name is " & name & "."
```

What i want to do is set the text in the name variable in Italics when it is displayed, like this.

Hello my name is *Bob*.

Best I've been able to find is to do with selection ranges, but not had any luck with that.

Cheers!

Comment: Please clarify, VB6 or VB.NET.

Comment: Ah apologies. I am using Visual Studio 2010, which I believe is .net?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Me.RichTextBox1.Rtf = "{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Calibri;}} hello my name is \i Bob\i0 \par}"
```

If you use wordpad to write some sample text, save it in rtf format and then open the file in notepad, you will get something to start with.  You can remove some of what wordpad adds (like the program that generated it) but it looks like you have to leave in at least the code page and at least one font.

Comment: Sorry, having a few issues understanding your answer. Are you recommending exporting the string into wordpad, altering it by adding the italic formatting then importing it back into VB in order to display it with italic formatting applied?

Comment: First, you need to set the .Rtf property of the rich text box, instead of the .text property.

Comment: I was thinking of using wordpad more as a way of discovering the markup required for rtf.  Once you know the required beginning and ending of the rtf string, and that \i and \i0 start and end italics, you can build your own rtf strings.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim BO As New Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.italic) ' Italic
  richtextbox1.text = "Hello my name is " 
  richtextbox1.selectionfont = BO
  richtextbox1.appendtext(name)
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a little routine that does this:

```
Private Sub changeRTF(ByVal strToChange As String, ByRef richTextBox As RichTextBox, ByVal color As Color, Optional ByVal ital As Boolean = False, Optional ByVal bold As Boolean = False, Optional ByVal pointSize As Single = -1)
    richTextBox.SelectionStart = richTextBox.Find(strToChange, RichTextBoxFinds.MatchCase)

    If ital And bold Then
        richTextBox.SelectionFont = New Font(richTextBox.Font, FontStyle.Bold + FontStyle.Italic)
    Else
        If ital Then richTextBox.SelectionFont = New Font(richTextBox.Font, FontStyle.Italic)
        If bold Then richTextBox.SelectionFont = New Font(richTextBox.Font, FontStyle.Bold)
    End If

    richTextBox.SelectionColor = color

    Dim originalFontFamily As FontFamily = richTextBox.SelectionFont.FontFamily
    Dim originalFontStyle As FontStyle = richTextBox.SelectionFont.Style

    If pointSize > 0 Then richTextBox.SelectionFont = New Font(originalFontFamily, pointSize, originalFontStyle)
End Sub
```

So, you would create your text, and then call `changeRTF("Bob",richtextbox1,color.gold,true)`.

The only problem with this code is it currently only finds the first existence of the string you are looking for. I use it to highlight titles so it hasn't been a problem so far (I don't repeat the titles).