# Change Font Style on All Instances of a String in a RichTextBox

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox, font-style

I'm working on a VB.NET 4.5 project in VS2013.

I have a richtextbox on a form and when a button is clicked I need to toggle the BOLD setting on all instances of a specific string found in the richtextbox.

I put together some code based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362957/visual-basic-richtextbox-setting-specific-text-to-italic-font-style).

```
Private Sub ToggleBold()

    rtxtOutputText.SelectionStart = rtxtOutputText.Find("@#$%", RichTextBoxFinds.None)

    rtxtOutputText.SelectionFont = New Font(rtxtOutputText.Font, FontStyle.Bold)
End Sub
```

However when the toggle bold button is clicked it only bolds the first instance of the string "@#$%".

How can I set all instances of the string to bold? There can also be several of them strung together ("@#$%@#$%@#$%"), so each of those would need to be bolded too.

(I know I mentioned *toggling* bold, but I'll set up the toggle portion later, right now I'm just trying to get the bold on all instances working right...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a loop to it and use the [**`RichTextBox.Find(String, Int32, RichTextBoxFinds)` overload**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9be0980x(v=vs.110).aspx) to specify from where to start looking. Look from the current index + 1 so that it doesn't return the same again.

You also ought to actually *select* the word as well, so that you're sure the bold applies to the current instance **only** and not the text around it.

```
Private Sub ToggleBold()
    'Stop the control from redrawing itself while we process it.
    rtxtOutputText.SuspendLayout()

    Dim LookFor As String = "@#$%"
    Dim PreviousPosition As Integer = rtxtOutputText.SelectionStart
    Dim PreviousSelection As Integer = rtxtOutputText.SelectionLength
    Dim SelectionIndex As Integer = -1

    Using BoldFont As New Font(rtxtOutputText.Font, FontStyle.Bold)
        While True
            SelectionIndex = rtxtOutputText.Find(LookFor, SelectionIndex + 1, RichTextBoxFinds.None)

            If SelectionIndex < 0 Then Exit While 'No more matches found.

            rtxtOutputText.SelectionStart = SelectionIndex
            rtxtOutputText.SelectionLength = LookFor.Length

            rtxtOutputText.SelectionFont = BoldFont
        End While
    End Using

    'Allow the control to redraw itself again.
    rtxtOutputText.ResumeLayout()

    'Restore the previous selection.
    rtxtOutputText.SelectionStart = PreviousPosition
    rtxtOutputText.SelectionLength = PreviousSelection
End Sub
```

Credit to Plutonix for telling me to dispose the font.

Comment: It would be better to define the highlight/selected/special  Font *once* and just reuse the same instance of it.  Fonts are IDisposable

Comment: @Plutonix : You're certainly right about that! I thought about doing so but changed my mind :). Also, can one dispose the new font object safely here without it affecting the control? Or should I just define it once like the string instance?

Comment: You could put it in a `Using` block, but why create the same new Font over and over and over in the first place?

Comment: @Plutonix : I already put it in a `Using` block outside the loop. However I was just curious if disposing it affected the `RichTextBox` in some way.

Comment: @marky : Glad I could help! Good luck with your project!